# I am trying to add a column of type number into a table(in oracle) with value 0 at odd number row and 1 at even number row

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add a column of type number into a table(in oracle) with value 0 at odd number row and 1 at even number row

Comment: Tables are not ordered on their own.  How do you identify the "number" of a row?  Once you have figured that out, you might have your answer.  For example, perhaps you have an auto-incrementing field in the table.  Then, your odd and even would just be a mod 2 calculation on that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update  set = case when mod(rownum,2)=0 then 1 else 0 end
Ex:- update tblMaster set flag = case when mod(rownum,2)=0 then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*,
       1 - MOD( ROWNUM, 2 ) AS odd_even
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER BY col1 -- ...
)
```

Comment: This assumes facts not in evidence :-)  Why order by col1 and not, for example, by col1 nulls first, or by col1 desc? What's the rush - why not wait for the OP to clarify?

Comment: Because clarifying the question is not going to substantially alter the methodology. You order the table by something and then, once ordered, you use MODULUS 2 of the row number. The OP can specify whatever order they want but if you want to be pedantic then I'll update the answer when the OP updates the question.

Comment: Also, you might note that I put `-- ...` after the order by to indicate that you can continue/modify the order by however you want.